# JQuery Mobile Theme is replacing HTML elements I have placed globally in the background

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am updating an older project and in the process I am trying to update JQuery to latest. It has all gone fine so far except for updating from JQuery Mobile CSS version 1.0a3 to the latest 1.3.2 (structure + theme).

The latest JQuery Mobile CSS theme (not structure) is placing a default background over top of the images I want displayed globally (this way the images won't move/fade on page change).

I also can't just use the structure CSS because the theme CSS provides the nice navigation across the top of pages.

Here is an example of the HTML:

```
<!--display images in background-->    
<img id="background" src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50.png" />
<img id="corner-bottomright" src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50.png" />
<img id="corner-bottomleft" src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50.png" />
<img id="corner-topleft" src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50.png" />
<img id="title" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x50.png" />
<img id="navbar" src="http://www.placehold.it/50x100.png" />

<!--main page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page1" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" style="padding:0px;height:100%;background-size:100%;">
    <div data-role="content" style="padding:0px;">
        <a href="#page3"><img id="corner-topright" src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50.png" /></a>
    </div>
</div>

<!--info page-->
<div data-role="page" id="page3" data-add-back-btn="true" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" style="height:100%;background-size:100%;">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Build Information</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="deviceinfo">
        <p>Your device information:</p>
        <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle using CSS 1.3.2](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvm75/2/)

[JSFiddle using CSS 1.0a3](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvm75/3/) (works with webkit only)

Was this deprecated at some point? What is the cleanest way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some CSS classes were added in later versions that display a background. Setting the `background` on these elements to transparent with an `!important` flag resolves the issue.

```
.ui-page, .ui-body-c, .ui-page-active, .ui-overlay-c, .ui-mobile-viewport
{
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

And a [JSFiddle showing how it should work](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvm75/4/).

I know this solution is sloppy so if somebody answers this question with cleaner code I will award you the best answer.